# Manter zero após a vírgula usando o tipo float?

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho um banco de dados onde ficam armazenados valores de produtos.

Quando há ocorrência de números com zero após a vírgulas eles vem sem o zero.

Fiz um teste e com decimal deu certo, mas minha aplicação usa o tipo **float**, então preciso fazer funcionar com **float**.

```
decimal numero = decimal.Parse("50,00");
string resultado = numero.ToString();
Console.Write(resultado); /* Resultado: 50,00 */
```

Estou usando um float que permite nulos:

```
float? numero = null;
```

Comment: O resultado do seu código é `5000` para mim. `Decimal.Parse` parece ignorar vírgulas. Além disso os tipos decimais não armazenam a quantidade de zeros a direita do número original, mas você pode forçar uma quantidade específica ao formatar como uma string novamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simples, use `ToString`:

```
resultado.ToString("N2");
```

Aonde `2` é o número de casas decimais.

[Referência](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f71z6k0c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Funcionou, como meu float é um **Nullable** eu tive apenas que adicionar o parâmetro **value**: `resultado.Value.ToString("N2");`, obrigado.

Comment: Sim, no caso de `Nullable`s é uma boa prática checar se ele tem um valor antes de usá-lo com `HasValue` ou `GetValueOrDefault`.

Answer (score 2):

Se o problema for exibir esse valor sem o zero após a vírgula então você pode tentar utilizar o format do String para exibir da forma que você deseja:

```
float valor = 1.00f;

Console.WriteLine(valor); // 1
Console.WriteLine(valor.ToString("0.00")); // 1,00
```

Answer (score 0):

Resposta curta: nunca use float ;-)

Resposta longa: float não é capaz de manter o número exatamente como você o descreve. Experimente fazer isso no console do Chrome, por exemplo:

```
0.1 * 0.2
```

A resposta será
    0.020000000000000004

Porque há falhas no float na forma de como o número é colocado na memória e então 0.02 não é armazenado exatamente desta forma.

Se você realiza cálculos nestes números, sempre, SEMPRE utilize DECIMAL (e no SQL, NUMBER(X, Y), onde X é a quantidade total de dígitos e Y é a quantidade após o ponto decimal).

Qualquer outro uso com single ou double lhe trará problemas de arredondamento (coisa que até o Excel tem problemas).

Single ou float são rápidos para fazer outras coisas, como gráficos, DirectX, etc... mas para cálculos, especialmente monetários, nunca os utilize.

Comment: Arredondamentos são bastante aceitáveis quando a exatidão do resultado não é importante, apenas a magnitude. Evite generalizar assim. Para calculos monetários o ideal é usar um ponto fixo (contar centavos em vez de reais por exemplo). Adicionalmente, essa resposta não responde ao que foi perguntado.